# Asynchronous to Synchronous mapping - Join two separate HTTP calls

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, semaphore

I have a problem statement where a product is making an outbound call to a self-hosted service in a synchronous way, and is expecting the response in synchronous manner.

In order to provide the response, my self hosted service needs to do a lot of async operations and goes to on-prem. On-prem sends back the response to receiver service, and while sending the response back to self-hosted service, I am not able to identify the response belongs to which request.

I have read about semaphore, and was wondering if that could be used to solve this.

For example:

1. Main state of each thread in Semaphore
2. Let the self hosted service do the usual work, and wait for something
3. Once I have the response from on-prem and SNS sends an event, awake to do the further processing

High-level architecture

[image: Diagram]

**Kindly note**: I can't change the flow or the architecture

Comment: When you send more than one message before getting a response you have to be able to associate the send message with the receive message by an ID because response may not be returned in same order that gets sent.  When you are guaranteed the response are return in same order as what was sent than you can use a simple queue to match the sent to the received.  When you do not have an ID or messages are not return in order sent you can only sent one message at a time.  Then to synchronize your sent and receive message using a semaphore.

Comment: See following for semaphore in c# : See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone?view=net-7.0&force_isolation=true

Comment: Please provide your code!